# Mostrar paginas de error(deny_info) squid proxy

Tags: linux, proxy

Por ejemplo tengo las siguientes ACLs
acl mortales src "/etc/squid/listas/mortales"
acl bloquear url_regex "/etc/listas/bloqueo"

```
    http_access allow mortales !bloqueo
    error_directory /usr/share/squid/errors/en/
    deny_info ERR_ACCESS_DENIED mortales
```

El problema es con el explorador, porque squid si me bloquea los sitios de la lista, pero no me muestra las paginas de error personalziadas de squid, solo se muestran las paginas de error genericas de los exploradores. Encontr la siguiente informacion en este sitio http://wiki.squid-cache.org/Features/CustomErrors, pero tambien lei que ya las nuevas versiones de los exploradores solo muestran sus paginas genericas de error y no le permiten al squid usar las suyas

Comment: ***Error: your question has been written in an unsupported language. Please verify that your question use the accepted language for [es.so], which is spanish. Click on [edit] and translate your question, otherwise it will be closed.***